# Articles discussing examples of Kaluza-Klein Reduction

Tags: resource-recommendations, compactification, kaluza-klein

The notes for my class on Kaluza-Klein reduction are a bit all over the place and at times it's difficult to follow what's going on. (I plan on asking a specific question about an example later).

For now, are there any resources that introduce Kaluza-Klein reduction with some worked examples, apart from the simple Minkowski space with a circle attached. I'd like to see some explicit examples where we have a higher dimensional torus for example.

A treatment including supergravity would be a plus.

Comment: How about any ol' string book: Compactifications are everywhere!

Comment: Did you had a look at this one [KALUZA-KLEIN SUPERGRAVITY](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(86)90163-8)? (and references therein)

Comment: Chis Pope's notes are very useful - http://people.physics.tamu.edu/pope/ihplec.pdf

Comment: Try going to the source!  Read their papers.  There is a book by Peter Bergmann in GR, in Dover print (cheap), and there is an appendix on K-K theory that derives everything from scratch.  Another is the Dawning of Gauge Theory by O'Raifeartaigh